# Highest value from sub-arrays in documents

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this requirement, where i have a collection as below:

```
{ 
      "_id" : 1, 
      "name" : "sam", 
      "Array" : [ 
          { "K" : "A", "V" : 8 }, 
          { "K" : "B", "V" : 5 }, 
          { "K" : "C", "V" : 13 } 
      ] 
},
{ 
    "_id" : 2, 
    "name" : "tom", 
    "Array" : [ 
        { "K" : "D", "V" : 12 }, 
        { "K" : "E", "V" : 14 }, 
        { "K" : "F", "V" : 2 } 
    ]
},
{ 
    "_id" : 3, 
    "name" : "jim", 
    "Array" : [ 
        { "K" : "G", "V" : 9 }, 
        { "K" : "H", "V" : 4 },
        { "K" : "I", "V" : 2 } 
    ] 
}
```

I would like to run a query that returns the sub-document of each _id with the highest "V", so in that case I would get:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "sam", "Array" : [ { "K" : "C", "V" : 13 } ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "tom", "Array" : [ { "K" : "E", "V" : 14 } ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "jim", "Array" : [ { "K" : "G", "V" : 9 } ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You use can select only the sub-documents where the `V` field's value is equal to the maximum value in the array using [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter) and the [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) operator.

The [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) pipeline stage is used here to specify all other fields in the document.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      "$addFields":{
         "Array":{
            "$filter":{
               "input":"$Array",
               "cond":{
                  "$eq":[
                     "$$this.V",
                     {
                        "$max":"$Array.V"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```